# datagrid speed issue

Tags: asp.net

i m binding gridview in asp.net application...
i m about to bind some thousand records in datagrid...
on RowDataBound event of the grid i need to check if the log in user is authorised to view the perticuler record...so i need to send database request...like wise such other two to three operation requires to send request to database....

about three to four request are sended to database during each row bound of the gridview...is it effective on speed of the grid?

Comment: Are you storing your access permissions in the same database?

Answer (score 2):

You are performing your permission checks too late. Filter the data before you try to bind it to the grid. Preferably on the initial data access.

Comment: thank for the reply, can you please tell me that is it physible to call db request during Rowdatabound event of Grid

Comment: Do you mean "is it possible"? Yes it is possible but you really shouldn't do it. You should aim to do get all of the information for display before you attempt to bind it/display it. If you can perform the filtering in the database, do it there, otherwise, use Linq to filter what comes back from the database, but never do a db call for every row unless it can't be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

First of all turn off your ViewState for the grid as you are bidding the rows.